# is this possible to drag forward or reverse in qml charts, if possible can anybody share me the logic

Tags: qt, qml

```js
    ChartView {
        id: chartView
        width: 900
        height: 250
        //        anchors.fill: parent
        x: 250
        y: 0
        animationOptions: ChartView.NoAnimation
        antialiasing: true
        backgroundColor: "#1f1f1f"

        Rectangle{
                id: rectang
                color: "black"
                opacity: 0.6
                visible: false
            }

            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                acceptedButtons: Qt.AllButtons
                onPressed: {
                    rectang.x = mouseX; rectang.y = mouseY; rectangle.visible = true
                }
                onMouseXChanged: {rectang.width = mouseX - rectang.x}
                onMouseYChanged: {rectang.height = mouseY - rectang.y}
                onReleased: {
                    if(!isTimerStoped)
                    {
//                        objMv.stopTimer();
                        isTimerStoped=true;
                        chartView.zoomIn(Qt.rect(rectang.x, rectang.y, rectang.width, rectang.height))
                        rectang.visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chartView.zoomReset();
                        isTimerStoped=false;
//                        objMv.startTimer();
                    }
                }
            }

        ToolTip {
            id: id_tooltip
            contentItem: Text{
                color: "#21be2b"
                text: id_tooltip.text
            }
            background: Rectangle {
                border.color: "#21be2b"
            }
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisY1
            min: -10
            max: 100
            gridVisible: false
            color: "#ffffff"
            labelsColor: "#ffffff"
            labelFormat: "%.0f"
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisX
            min: 0
            max: 100
            gridVisible: false
            color: "#ffffff"
            labelsColor: "#ffffff"
            labelFormat: "%.0f"
            //            tickCount: 25
        }

        SplineSeries{
            id: lineSeries1
            name: "signal 1"
            color: "white"
            axisX: axisX
            axisY: axisY1
            onHovered: {
                var p = chartView.mapToPosition(point)
                var text = qsTr("x: %1, y: %2").arg(point.x).arg(point.y)
                id_tooltip.x = p.x
                id_tooltip.y = p.y - id_tooltip.height
                id_tooltip.text = text
                //id_tooltip.timeout = 1000
                id_tooltip.visible = true
            }
        }
    }
```

is this possible to drag forward or reverse in **qml charts**, if possible can anybody share me the logic
any mouse event i have to use?
please give us some idea

below was my code which only functioning for chart and tooltip, I require is if chart is going left to right  if user wants to stop on that time and he wants see history of the graph by drag option